# VBA copy paste date format changing itself

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub addworksheet()

Worksheets("worksheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets("worksheet1")
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
ActiveSheet.Name = "worksheet2"
End Sub
```

I want to copy the value of worksheet1 to worksheet2. The date format in my worksheet1 is mm/dd/yyyy. After me running this macro, my worksheet2 date format is dd/mm/yyyy. How do I copy the value of worksheet 1?

Comment: Does copy > paste special, values produce the same result?

Comment: I try paste special with values will produce the same result